# ViewPager gives Out Of Memory Error

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have implemented an ViewPager and it gives me an Out Of Memory error and I can't figure out why is that. I have around 11 images to show, each image having around 500 kb(size on disk) and they are .jpg format.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmw_gallery);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private int[] mImages = new int[] {
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_01,
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_02,
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_03,
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_04,
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_05,
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_06,
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_07,
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_08,
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_09,
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_11,
    R.drawable.bmw_1series_3door_wallpaper_12
};

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return mImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
  return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  Context context = MainActivity.this;
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
  imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

  imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
  ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
  return imageView;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
    View view = (View)o;
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
    view = null;
}


}



}
```

What am I doing wrong or what is missing from my code ?

Comment: Is "500kb" referring to the size on disk, or the decoded size in RAM?

Comment: Referring to the size on disk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html
I just implemented the BitmapFun project inside mine. This way the application is working really good and I don't get the Out of Memory Error anymore .

Comment: can you share an example of it without using fragments? just a simple viewpager with the code that you used?

Answer (score 10):

A 500KB JPEG image on disk will take up a lot more heap space than that.

For example, I have a digital photo here that is 494KB, with a resolution of 1455 x 1029. If I were to load that into an Android app, it would consume 1455x1029x3 = 4.3MB of heap space. If you have 11 images of similar characteristics, combined they will consume > 40MB. Most devices have 16-32MB of heap space per process.

If you want to ship 11 drawable resources (in this case, possibly images that will get you sued into oblivion by BMW), you will need to have smaller images.

Comment: There is no concern about getting sued by BMW because the app won't be released on MarketPlace, is just a project I have.

Comment: So the only chance to make it use less resources  and not get that error is to modify their size on disk?

Comment: @CatalinH: Assuming that you want to use drawable resources, yes. More accurately, you need lower-resolution images. The problem is that, AFAIK, you cannot evict resources from memory. If these images were files on the filesystem, and you were loading them in yourself using `BitmapFactory`, then you might have more options for trying to ensure that bitmap memory is reused (see `inBitmap` on `BitmapFactory.Options`), in which case you would better control your memory consumption. However, that makes for a much more complicated app.

Comment: Can you lead me please to an example which loads images from Internal/External/Web resource and doesn't have so much memory consumption ?

Comment: @CatalinH: There are open source image caches that you can use, easily available via a Web search. There is also coverage of this topic in the Android developer documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the SAME problem while displaying high resolution images in viewpager. I have searched and applied all the android bitmap solutions given in http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html and the following caches mekanism in the link. but none of them work. not any right solution anywhere.

Then I figured out that the problem is : I couldnt use the drawable folder structure right. I was keeping high resolution images in mdpi and hdpi folders . this cause android scale up the images to the ultra sizes. 100 kb image was causing 20 mb increase in memory thanks to the android monitor / memory section.
so I have added these ultra resolution images to xxhdpi folder , then It was FIXED  suddenly. then my image slider work flawlessly with high resolution images

Comment: @kksal55 thanks my friend. I haven't seen a downside yet